# A program that compares 2 strings in C

Tags: c, compare

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char alegere[10];
    int a;
    printf ("Alege natura matricei tale: (Numere/Caractere)");
    scanf ("%s", &alegere[10]);
    if (strcmp(alegere, "Numere") == 0){
        printf("a");
    } else 
        printf ("b");
    return 0;
}
```

It should compare my string that I'm writing from the keyboard with the string" Numere", but if i tipe the string "Numere" or any other string the outcome will be the same, i will get printed "b"... So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @user3121023 I get the same outcome

Comment: Did this code compile properly?, string compare should be  (strcmp(alegere, "Numere") == 0)..

Comment: `#include <string.h>`

Comment: @WeatherVane I had it, just forgot to type it here.

Comment: Anything else you forgot, such as a `)`? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. "Verifiable" means by *you* so that we are not answering a fictitious question.

Comment: @HardikSanghvi Yes.. I forgot that ), but it still does not do what it is suposed to do.

Comment: use:- scanf ("%s", alegere);

Comment: Yes it does. After the suggested corrections I enter `Numere` and it prints `a`.

Comment: There is an unused variable 'a'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things:

1. As suggested in the comments, you should use `"%9s"` instead of `"%s"` in your `scanf`. This ensures that the number of characters input does not overflow your array `alegere` which only has room for 10 characters. (Why 9 instead of 10? Because C-strings are [null terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).)
2. You are missing a `)` in your call to `strcmp`.
3. `&alegere[10]` does not do what you want; `&alegere[10]` is the memory address of `alegere[10]`, or one past the end of your array. This means that your `scanf` invokes undefined behavior. Replace this with either `&alegere[0]` or, more simply `alegere`.

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char alegere[10];
    printf ("Alege natura matricei tale: (Numere/Caractere)");
    scanf ("%9s", alegere);
    if (strcmp(alegere, "Numere") == 0){
        printf("a");
    } else
        printf ("b");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: &alegere[0] <==> alegere + 0 <==> alegere

Comment: Sry, I wrote it fast. The 3rd hint you wrote was my problem, now I understand why it wasn't working

Answer (score 3):

1. Braces issue change this

> `if (strcmp(alegere, "Numere" == 0)`

to

```
if (strcmp(alegere, "Numere") == 0)
```

2. Scan Memory is not pointing to the start of the address

> `scanf ("%s", &alegere[10]);`
>   to 
>   `scanf ("%s", alegere);` // %9s is a very good suggestion by other users